# Scala - how to call a method which expects a Map

Tags: scala, hashmap

I have a scala method:

```
def commitSync(offsets: Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata]) = {
   consumer.commitSync(offsets.asJava)
}
```

[TopicPartition](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/TopicPartition.html) is a class with 2 parameters (`String` and `Int`):
`TopicPartition(java.lang.String topic, int partition)`. 
Making it in scala like this:

`val tp = new TopicPartition("sometopicname", 99)`

[OffsetAndMetadata](http://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/OffsetAndMetadata.html) is public kafka class with type 'long' in it:
`OffsetAndMetadata​(long offset)`

How to call now a method `commitSync` with these 2 parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you declare two case classes

```
case class TopicPartition(str:String,intVal:Int)
case class OffsetAndMetadata(longVal:Long)
```

Now you create a map with these values

```
val offsets = Map(TopicPartition("sometopicname", 99) -> OffsetAndMetadata(999999))
```

You can now call your function commitSync as

```
commitSync(offsets)
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference between using `val tp = new TopicPartition("sometopicname", 99)` and `case class TopicPartition(str:String,intVal:Int)`

Comment: For one, you are calling a new instance of a `class`. For the other, you are defining a `case class`, as you would define a function or a variable. Case classes are great for storing data and functions, as they generate a lot of helpful stuff behind the scenes which you would have to write out explicitly in a language like Java. To create a new case class, you would just do `val tp = TopicPartition("sometopicname", 99)` (one of the features of case classes is that the `new` keyword is redundant).

Comment: @Joe Please let me know if you have any further doubts so that I can clarify them. If the answer is sufficient, please do accept the solution.

Comment: @Joe more on case classes here: https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/classes_vs_case_classes :)

Comment: Thanks James and Chaitanya!

Comment: Got error: `Error:(223, 25) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata]
 required: Map[org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata]
    consumer.commitSync(offsets)`

Answer (score 1):

Create a Map within the function call:

```
def commitSync(input: Map[String, Int]) = ??? // whatever

commitSync(Map("my string" -> 10))
```

---

Alternatively, you can define a Map as a `val` and pass it in as a parameter.

```
val map = Map("my string" -> 10)

commitSync(map)
```

---

Specifically with your example, something like this would work:

```
case class TopicPartition(val1: String, val2: Int)
case class OffsetAndMetadata(val1: Long)

def commitSync(input: Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata]) = ??? // whatever

val map = Map(TopicPartition("string", 123) -> OffsetAndMetadata(1234567890))

commitSync(map)
```

Comment: Got type mismatch error:  `Error:(224, 25) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata]
 required: Map[org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata]
    consumer.commitSync(map)` (tried all examples).

Comment: I thought you were using your own classes `TopicPartition` and `OffsetAndMetadata` and not some pre-defined classes. If you get rid of the `case class` definitions and change the Map to `Map(new TopicPartition("string", 123) -> new OffsetAndMetadata(1234567890))`, does it work?

Comment: The main point of the answer was that if you want to pass a Map as a parameter, you need to write it in the format that I suggested. For example, if you have a function `def function(input: Map[String, String])`, you would create the map with something like 'val map = Map("w" -> "x", "y" -> "z")' (etc). As in, `Map[LeftThing, RightThing]` is written as `Map(LeftThing -> RightThing, LeftThing -> RightThing)` (with the arrow in between them and having the different entries separated by commas).

Comment: import kafka.common.OffsetAndMetadata  ; val map = Map(new TopicPartition("string", 123) -> new OffsetAndMetadata(1234567890)); 
    commitSync(map)  :::  Error:(224, 78) type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1234567890)
 required: kafka.common.OffsetMetadata
    val map = Map(new TopicPartition("string", 123) -> new OffsetAndMetadata(1234567890));  Error:(229, 25) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,kafka.common.OffsetAndMetadata]
 required: Map[org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata]

Comment: Sorry. Edited question with a hyperlink to that class (OffsetAndMetadata).

Comment: Not sure what the second error is about as it is finding an Int where you have defined an OffsetAndMetadata... the second error looks like the method is expecting one type of Map and receiving an `immutable.Map` instead. Maybe this answer will help with that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122644/8230810

Comment: Do you know what is this throwing an error? `val map2 = Map(new TopicPartition("string", 123) -> new kafka.common.OffsetAndMetadata(1234567890));`  :::  :Error:(223, 92) `type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1234567890)
 required: kafka.common.OffsetMetadata
    val map2 = Map(new TopicPartition("string", 123) -> new kafka.common.OffsetAndMetadata(1234567890));`   Is is Int vs Long or?